# XLS-XML not showing data XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using birt and the file is a `xls` but `xml` format.
Can someone tell me why is not working? I tried a few changes, but none of them works;
If I put this:

```
<xsl:template match="/Workbook">
```

It will work in a wrong way, because it only throws inside `<body>`. After that I checked the  node path, and it's like this:

```
/Workbook/Worksheet[1]/Table[1]/Row[1]/Cell[1]
```

I have my `xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <Author/>
        <Title/>
        <Description/>
        <Subject/>
    </DocumentProperties>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Report">
<ss:Table>
    <ss:Column ss:Width="192.0" ss:AutoFitWidth="0"/>
    <ss:Column ss:Width="192.0" ss:AutoFitWidth="0"/>
    <ss:Column ss:Width="192.0" ss:AutoFitWidth="0"/>
    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
        <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="20">
            <Data ss:Type="String">A</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="20">
            <Data ss:Type="String">B</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="20">
            <Data ss:Type="String">C</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</ss:Table>
<WorksheetOptions>
</WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

And my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" >
<xsl:template match="/">
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
</head>
<body class="">
    <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="Workbook/Worksheet/ss:Table">
            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Cell">                     
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Data" />
                        </td>                   
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of namespaces! Ignore them at your peril...

The root element of your XML looks like this:

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
```

The `xmlns` is a default namespace declaration. It means the `Workbook` and all descendants belong to that namespace (unless overridden by another one).

Now, an element in a namespace is different from a similarly named element in a different namespace, or one with no space at all.

Therefore, when you do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Workbook/Worksheet/ss:Table">
```

The `Workbook` and `Worksheet` will not match the XML because it is look for elements with no namespace.

The solution, is to declare the namespace in the XSLT, and prefix the relative elements. In fact, the namespace is already declared in your XSLT. You can use the `ss` prefix throughout. Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" >
<xsl:template match="/">
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
</head>
<body class="">
    <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table">
            <xsl:for-each select="ss:Row">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">                     
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ss:Data" />
                        </td>                   
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```